# Generating value from given density function

Tags: self-study, simulation, random-generation, rejection-sampling

[image: 1]

In this question, I do not understand how to create the random values from this density function. The plot histogram part of the question is not problematic. Would someone please give me a hint as to how to generate the random values?

Comment: When you edit to clarify your question, you'll also need to read our [help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) particularly the section in relation to homework-style questions.

Comment: @Glen_b OP did as requested, I just patched up the English.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89822 for a large list of resources and methods.  Just about *any* method will work nicely with this distribution.

Comment: @whuber The cited post deals with a specific density and it seems that Glen_b recommended inverse probability transformation for that case once the actual distribution was pinned down. I thought this one is a little tricky because 2 is a break  point where the density changes height. Also in the original post the OP mentioned a rejection method and I am not sure why that was edited out. I am not sure why the OP wanted to generate a histogram with 50 observations when the distribution is known but perhaps he wanted to compare the known density with the shape of the histogram.

Comment: Also there is not a unique way to generate a histogram.  Bin size is an issue and it is connected to sample size.  With 50 observations would you be able to see the shift in the density at the break point where x=2.  If interested in that maybe 2 should be an endpoint of a bin in the histogram.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: while the density is discontinuous in $x=2$, the cdf is _not_ discontinuous at all, hence there is absolutely no difficulty whatsoever with applying the inverse cdf method.

Comment: Hint: Simple, efficient methods applicable to this situation include modeling $f$ as a mixture of uniforms, rejection sampling (relative to a uniform distribution), and inverting the CDF. You can also express this as a transformation of a simpler variable.  The following transformation, which is motivated by inspecting the graph of $f$, is particularly efficient and amusing. The code is in `R`: `f <- function(n) {
  x <- runif(n, -14, 10);
  ifelse(x < 0, -x/7, x)
};
hist(f(50))`

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** compute the associated cdf
$$F(x)=\int_0^x f(y)\,\text{d}y\qquad 0\le x\le 8$$
and solve $$F(x)=u\qquad 0<u<1$$[This is the inverse cdf generation method.]